# Как разбить строку по шаблону регулярного выражения?

Tags: python, регулярные-выражения

Из строки:

```
'товар1 5шт объект 3ед изделие 7 единиц'
```

надо получить список:

```
['товар1','объект','изделие']
```

Такой пример строки:

```
'опрыскиватель gig 600-2 шт.,косилка роторная пу-270 - 2 ед., опрыскиватель 2000 л.- 1 штука'
```

При этом, разбиение должно происходить по шаблону регулярного выражения, а не по запятой.

Comment: Приведите в вопросе вашу попытку решения. Какой шаблон вы имете ввиду в заголовке - непонятно.

Comment: Так ответы же ниже.

Comment: А причём здесь ответы? Вы задали вопрос и он должен быть понятен, как с ответами, так и без них.

Comment: Я поправил, так будет по-лучше, согласен.

Comment: Ну не совсем чтобы уж, но получше. Учтите пожалуйста на будущее, вопросы, которые содержат только задание обычно закрываются. Всегда добавляйте: "Пробую так, получаю то-то, а надо вот это".  Только не говорите, что вам это сложно, такие регулярки сейчас в школе проходят.

Comment: Спасибо. Соглашусь, что немного сочканул. Буду более конструктивен и понятен.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

попробуйте так:

```
In [18]: s = 'опрыскиватель gig 600-2 шт.,косилка роторная пу-270 - 2 ед., опрыскиватель 2000 л.- 1 штука'

In [19]: pat = r"\d+\s*(?:единиц|ед|штук\w*|шт\w*)[\s\.,]*"

In [20]: re.split(pat, s)
Out[20]:
['опрыскиватель gig 600-',
 'косилка роторная пу-270 - ',
 'опрыскиватель 2000 л.- ',
 '']
```